# calling YoloV5 model multiple times in multithreaded environment causing GPU hung up

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, yolo, yolov5

I am running multiple ML models on GPU in my service and calling then concurrently. After few multiple calls and little heave the GPU memory abruptly reaching to 100% and causing service hung up.

I have tried multiple ways on loading the model using PyTorch but nothing worked out for me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Do some research. If you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Please also check [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am working on a service where I am using multiple YOLO v5 custom trained models, but at the runtime, when I am getting its output in multithreaded environment, my GPU/CPU utilization went to 400% and service hung up. If you need any specific information, I am open for it.